# How to automatically next line the paragraph in table?

Tags: tables

How to automatically next line the paragraph in table ? It's automatically adjust my table width

```
        \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{multirow}


    \title{For Testing}
    \author{TEST }
    \date{August 2022}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{| c | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | R{5cm} |}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\footnotesize{\textbf{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont No.}}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\footnotesize{\textbf{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont In Charage}}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\footnotesize{\textbf{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Operation Description}}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\footnotesize{\textbf{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Remarks}}}\\
    \hline
    1 & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} & Collumn 3 & Collumn 4 \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    2 & & Collumn 3 & Collumn 4 \\
    \hline
    3 & Collumn 2 & Collumn 3 & Collumn 4 \\
    \hline
    4 &
    Collumn 2 &
    Collumn 3 &
    Collumn 4 \\
    \hline
    5 &
    Collumn 2 &
    Collumn 3 &
    Collumn 4 \\
    \hline
    6 &
    Collumn 2 &
    Collumn 3 &
    Collumn 4 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\\

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to TeX.se! L and R (uppercase) are not regular tabular columns, so your code doesn't compile. did you mean something like `p{5cm}`, or did you define custom columns L and R using the `array` package?

Comment: How or where are the `L` and `R` column types defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
\multirow{2}{=}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX}
```

(observe `=`)

- Your table code is a bit strange. I suggest to use `makecell` package and their macro `\thead` for which you can define font style as you like to have. By it replace `\multicolumn` in table code. For example as is done in the following MWE.
- Table is wider that text width. You need to change columns width accordingly.

**Edit:**
Ups, I upload wrong version of table code. Corrected now.

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{array, 
            makecell,
            multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


    \title{For Testing}
    \author{TEST }
    \date{August 2022}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | L{4cm} | L{3cm} | R{2.8cm}|}
    \hline
\thead{No.} 
    & \thead{In Charage}    
                & \thead{Operation\\ Description} 
                                & \thead{Remarks}   \\
    \hline
 1  & \multirow{2}{=}{XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX}
                & Collumn 3     & Collumn 4         \\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
 2  &           & Collumn 3     & Collumn 4         \\
    \hline
 3 & Collumn 2  & Collumn 3     & Collumn 4         \\
    \hline
 4 & Collumn 2  & Collumn 3     & Collumn 4         \\
    \hline 
 5 & Collumn 2  & Collumn 3     & Collumn 4         \\
 6 & Collumn 2  & Collumn 3     & Collumn 4         \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page laxout)

**Addendum:**
Nicer result and more simple table code you can get with use of the `tabularray` package. It has a bit different syntax, which is thoroughly described in the package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

    \title{For Testing}
    \author{TEST }
    \date{August 2022}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {c X[l] X[l] X[r]},
                 row{1}  = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, m},
                 vspan   = even
                 }
No. & In Charage    & Operation Description & Remarks       \\
 1  & \SetCell[r=2]{l}  XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX
                    & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
 2  &               & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
 3 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
 4 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
 5 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
 6 & Collumn 2      & Collumn 3             & Collumn 4     \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IN above example last three columns has equal width. But this you can simple with change columns widths ratio. For example:

```
colspec = {c X[0.8,l] X[0.8,l] X[1.4, r]},
```

[image]

Comment: how to align the thead and the other column into left and top using tabularray

Comment: @Udot, see package documentation :-). There is all explained! In answer I use alignments as you write in your document example. From answer je can see that  `X[l]` columns have left aligned cells contents. With `row{1} = {\font=\footnotesize}` will be contents of the first row (with columns headers) vertically top aligned.